# What is a System.Windows.Forms.Design.ToolStripAdornerWindowService+ToolStripAdornerWindow?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, windows-forms-designer

I saw this come up in the Properties window after adding and then deleting a ContextMenuStrip. What is it and what does it do?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched MSDN and the System.Windows.Forms.Design namespace doesn't seem to have either.
Perhaps a screenshot is in order?